# Why am I getting errors while calling context.getResources().getString(R.string.string) in my class?

Tags: java, android, getstring

Why am I getting errors while calling context.getResources().getString(R.string.string) in my class?
Using

```
context.getResources().getString(R.string.january);
```

just gives me

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f06002e
```

Heres the complete class:

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c){
    super(context, c);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View returnView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

    return returnView;
}

public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c){
    TextView firstname, surname, bday;

    firstname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstnameTextView);
    firstname.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(c.getColumnName(1))));

    surname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.surnameTextView);
    firstname.append(" " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(c.getColumnName(2))));

    bday = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.datepickerTextView);
    bday.setText("\n" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.january));
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: are you sure that your string.xml contains january string ?

Comment: or make clean build?

Comment: Please note that values in `strings.xml` are case-sensitive. So, "january" is not the same as "January". Maybe you defined "january" in upper case?!

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this, and theres nothing wrong in my strings.xml or how im calling it

Comment: Do you have several values*** folder with custom postfix name?

Comment: Did u import your. package. R?

Comment: @user2927356 : Try `bday.setText(R.string.january);`